# How to remove permission from channel for role - discord.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to create a lock command which sets the SEND_MESSAGES permission for the Verified role to false.

My code isn't working right now. How do I do this? I can't seem to figure out how to use Channel.overwritePermissions, many people say

```
channel.overwritePermissions(role, { 'SEND_MESSAGES': false })
```

but this doesn't work as the discord documentation has an example like this:

```
channel.overwritePermissions([
  {
     id: message.author.id,
     deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
  },
], 'Needed to change permissions');
```

it doesn't work for me either. Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are getting confused with two very similarly named methods. There's [`Channel.updateOverwrite`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite), which:

> "Updates Overwrites for a user or role in this channel. (creates if non-existent)"

And then there's also [`Channel.overwritePermissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions), which:

> Replaces the permission overwrites in this channel.

The main difference between these two methods is that `updateOverwrite` only changes the overwrites for one role/member. However, `overwritePermissions` completely deletes all previous overwrites and replaces them with whatever is specified.

You are probably looking for `updateOverwrite` if you only want to change the settings for one role. This method uses the format you showed in your first example, so you can just copy and paste that code.

```js
channel.updateOverwrite(role, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I had no idea this method existed. You're the best!

Comment: Haha glad I could help :)